# List Pref trouble android

Tags: android, preference

I am having trouble working with list pref. I am trying to match a list pref value to another value with if statement

I bet that doesnt make sense so I will post code...

stripedMain:

```
String stripeType = "";
void drawStriped() {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null) {
                    if (stripeType == "vert") 
                    {
                    android.util.Log.d("stripedLog", "working");    
                        }
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
.............
```

settings.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="firKey"
        android:title="Wallpaper Settings" >

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="hor"
            android:entries="@array/stripe_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/stripe_values"
            android:key="stripe_type"
            android:title="Type" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

shapes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">

    <string-array name="stripe_entries">
        <item>"Horizontal"</item>
        <item>"Vertical"</item>
         <item>"Both"</item>
          <item>"Both+CrossOver"</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="stripe_values">
        <item>"hor"</item>
        <item>"vert"</item>
         <item>"both"</item>
        <item>"bothOver"</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

This is not working and I have no idea why....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working coz yu havent fetched the default shared preferences to compare it with a string

so what you have to do is fetch it and then compare like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String stripeType = prefs.getString("stripe_type", "stripe_type")


    void drawStriped() {
                final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
                Canvas c = null;
                try {
                    c = holder.lockCanvas();
                    if (c != null) {
                        if (stripeType.equalsIgnoreCase("vert")) 
                        {
                        android.util.Log.d("stripedLog", "working");    
                            }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null)
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
```

Comment: thank you, your answer wasnt exactly spot on but it did help me figure the prob out. The prob was that I wasnt doing this:   if (stripeType.equalsIgnoreCase("vert"))